# How can I modify the inbuilt search bar of RenderDT in R Shiny to allow multiple entries separated by commas?

Tags: r, shiny, render, dt, multiple-entries

I have been trying to add multiple entries on the search bar of the renderdt table function on shiny.
for example on the following code, instead of having a new search bar, i want to modify the one which is inbuilt in renderDT and allow it to take multiple entries, comma separated; for example setosa,virginica should bring rows with both setosa and virginica. I found solutions to add a new search bar but i wanted to know if i can modify this one accordingly. Any help regarding this would be highly appreciated.

```
if (interactive()) {
  library(shiny)
  library(DT)
  shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(fluidRow(column(12, DTOutput('tbl')))),
    server = function(input, output) {
      output$tbl = renderDT(
        iris, options = list(lengthChange = FALSE)
      )
    }
  )
}
```

i tried something like this, but this adds another search bar option and that is unnecessary

```
if (interactive()) {
  library(shiny)
  library(DT)
  
  shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(
      fluidRow(DTOutput('tbl'))
    ),
    server = function(input, output) {
      output$tbl = renderDT({
        data <- iris
        
        searchItems <- unlist(strsplit(input$search, ",")) # Split input string by commas
        searchItems <- trimws(searchItems) # Remove leading/trailing whitespace
        
        filteredData <- data[data$Species %in% searchItems, ]
        
        datatable(filteredData, options = list(lengthChange = FALSE))
      })
    }
  )
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using the `filter` option in datatable? Which allows you to filter by each column. Alternatively, since this is in shiny you could create some selectInputs to filter the data first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code:

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)

callback <- function(sep) {
  sprintf('
$("div.search").append($("#mySearch"));
$("#mySearch").on("keyup redraw", function(){
  var splits = $("#mySearch").val().split("%s").filter(function(x){return x !=="";})
  var searchString = "(" + splits.join("|") + ")";
  table.search(searchString, true).draw(true);
});
', sep)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$style(HTML(".search {float: right;}"))),
  br(),
  tags$input(type = "text", id = "mySearch", placeholder = "Search"),
  DTOutput("dtable")
)

server <- function(input, output){
  
  output[["dtable"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      iris[c(1, 2, 51, 52, 101, 102),],
      options = list(
        dom = "l<'search'>rtip"
      ),
      callback = JS(callback(","))
    )
  }, server = FALSE)
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Personally I prefer the *search builder*:

```r
datatable(
  iris[c(1, 2, 51, 52, 101, 102),],
  extensions = "SearchBuilder",
  options = list(
    dom = "Qlfrtip", 
    searchbuilder = TRUE
  )
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so  much, the first one worked perfectly!